# Show Centered Text Next to Site's Icon

Tags: html, css

Complete noob here with HTML/CSS.

I'm trying to get something like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyiP3.jpg

Here is my code:

```
<div id="topbar">

    <div class="image">

      <img src="images/ghwlogo.png">

    </div>

    <div class="text">

      <h1>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</h1>

    </div>

</div>
```

I've tried floating the div topbar, then display-inline but it never displays horizontally.

I'm so confused. Following tutorials is easy-peasy, but when you need to figure out how to do this yourself, it's completely different.

I think I'm missing a step somewhere. I feel like this should be really easy but it's not.

Comment: How does the css look

Comment: I know I'm missing my CSS, I deleted my code. It wasn't correct anyway.

Comment: mark an answer as helpful if it worked out

Answer (score 2):

```css
img {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }

.subhead {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff"/>
  <h1 class='subhead'>
    TEXT
  </h1>
</div>
```

I removed some HTML; I only add more when I can't think of how to get the effect with just CSS. You can add some back, but you may have to set display: inline on some inner elements then.

Generally, a few different ways of putting elements horizontally:

**Floating:** Removes it from standard flow layout, and may interfere with the root element's total height. Was previously the preferred method of placement but I feel like there are better alternatives.

**Display Inline:** Treats an element a bit like text. Cannot have a custom height or various other attributes.

**Display Inline-Block:** Often a "fix-all" for me when I want something laid out horizontally, but to have other styling aspects like height, border, etc.

**Position Absolute:** You can make a higher element a "relative element" for absolute positioning by setting `position: relative` on it. Like floating this takes it out of layout, but it can even overlap elements; useful for certain things. Don't rely on absolute pixel amounts too much.

In my case, once things are laid out horizontally, vertical alignment is the next issue. Remember that adding content could make this block very very tall, so you can't just say "vertical-align to the bottom of the thing". Think of all elements in the div as simply letters in a paragraph; for the smaller ones, you're telling it how to align that one letter. For the biggest ones, you're telling it *where that "letter" is aligned compared to the others*. So, it's important to set vertical alignment how you want it on the image as well.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: updated answer per @Katana314 answer. I've maintained the OP's markup.

```
#topbar {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.image {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 5px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dgautsch/che0dtfk/

Answer (score 0):

You could make the image and the text a separate `div` and then have both of them under the `inline-block` attribute. The text `div` would need to have a `position: absolute` attribute, though, for formatting purposes.

After viewing the Fiddle, you can adjust the `left` position attribute accordingly to generate space. Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/kuLLd866/.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://gfx2.poged.com/poged/game_logo_default_fix.png?2492">
    </div>

    <div class="imagetext">
        <h1>Text text text</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image {
    display: inline-block;
}

.imagetext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```